# c power calculation, compiler optimization

Tags: c, optimization, numerical, stability

so I have recently been working with some probability distributions of order statistics. in that area it is quite common to see lots of formulas with high powers of numbers from the real interval [0, 1].

Consider numbers a ~ b ~ 0, both positive. I want to calculate something like a^n / b^m
where n, m are huge numbers.

My question is the following:
If I use C code like

```
double f(double a, double b, long m, long n)
{
    return( pow(a, n) / pow(b, m) );
}
```

will this be stable? The rule should be to first evaluate a^n, then b^m then divide, however if
a^n or b^m is small enough it will just be zero or NaN. Instead I could do something like

```
double g(double a, double b, long m, long n)
{
    double res;
    long i;
    res = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < min(m, n); ++i)
    {
        res = res * a / b;
    }
    if ( n > m )
    {
        res = res * pow(a, n - m);
    } else {
       res = res / pow(b, m - n);
    }
    return( res );
}
```

Do you know whether 1) is subject to optimization in such cases? If not, how would one handle such cases for a fast and stable evaluation?

Comment: To avoid such scenarios, would it be viable to compute in the log domain?  i.e. `result = exp(n*log(a) - m*log(b))`.  (Disclaimer: I'm definitely not a numerical expert.)

Comment: You want the second form. But don't use a `for` loop. Use `pow(a/b, min(m, n))` to reduce the number of operations. (Assuming `m` and `n` must be non-negative.)

Comment: Well, thanks! I guess there is no problem with combining both approaches using sum() and log(a)-log(b) :)

Comment: In your `a ~ b ~ 0`, is `~` supposed to denote approximate equality?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether `pow()` implements exponentiation by repeated multiplication, the answer is no. You can assume it's optimized, so any savings you might achieve by checking for a zero numerator is probably negligible. You *definitely* don't want to implement this with a `for()` loop that iterates through a huge number of floating-point calculations.

On the other hand, it's good practice to avoid dividing by zero.

I'd implement your function like this:

```
double f(double a, double b, long m, long n) {
  if (b == 0) {
    // return error or infinity.
  }
  if (m >= n)
    return pow(a / b, n) * pow(a, m - n);
  else 
    return pow(a / b, m) / pow(b, n - m);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be slightly better to have `else return pow(a / b, m) * pow(b, m - n);`?

Comment: Maybe; I don't know with modern floating-point processors. That's what profilers are for. :-)